# strange issues trying to install node-sass in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install node-sass on a clean node.js install on Windows. I've also installed Python.

I run the command: **npm install --save-dev --unsafe-perm node-sass**

After a long time I get this:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path P:\node_modules\iconv
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
npm ERR! MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0".
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.9.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\lc\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'P:\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'P:\\node_modules\\iconv\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'P:\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\lc\\.node-gyp\\15.9.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\lc\\.node-gyp\\15.9.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=P:\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\lc\\.node-gyp\\15.9.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=P:\\node_modules\\iconv',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'P:\\node_modules\\iconv\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
npm ERR! Warning: unrecognized setting VCCLCompilerTool/MultiProcessorCompilation
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (P:\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "P:\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd P:\node_modules\iconv
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.9.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: In order to use node-gyp you need to install python. Once I came across this bug it needed python 2.7. I do not know if it still a thing when using node-gyp in windows.

Comment: I've installed the latest version of Python and also node-gyp. everything else works as expected, but not this install

Comment: Maybe it is like i said, this could be the python specific version that has to be 2.7